# VirtualBox: create a serial port bridge to the same VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, com

I'd like to make a bridge between Serial Port 1 and Serial Port 2 on a VM.

Practically this would route all data from VM Serial Port 1 back to VM Serial Port 2 so that an application listening on Serial Port 2 can be accessed from within the VM.

This is what I tried (using VBoxManage) to do so:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm [VMname] --uartmode1 server \\.\pipe\com_1
vboxmanage modifyvm [VMname] --uartmode2 client \\.\pipe\com_1
```

When the VM starts both ports are operational though they don't seem to be routing any data. Although I'm not sure (how can I check this?).

It also generates following error in the UI:

> **Serial Ports: Port 2** page:
>
> There are currently duplicate port paths specified.

Is this the correct way of doing this and does VirtualBox contain a bug? Or is there a better way to perform this bridge?